How to override UUID from the database side
Can anyone suggest how to fix the gap at the legacy system design?

The column is defined at the Java source code side as
@Column(name="ID")
@Type(type="string")
private UUID id;


The column datatype on the database side is defined as datatype VARCHAR(36)
Of course - we have an issue, because Hibernate can't convert string to UUID automatically.

Databases' changes are more comfortable as of now (cheaper) than Java source code.


Are there any ways how to avoid the issue with converting?
I've tried:

change the database datatype to UUID; and
set the value NULL to the column for all records (Hibernate has loaded a 0 records in this case).


which hibernate are you using? From JPA 3.1 / Hibernate 6 if I remember correctly UUID is supported without any modifications

The main gap is in a different definitions by notation @Type and datatype, which was used for id (uuid). So, looks like, java not able to convert string to uuid automatically. I'm trying to avoid any java's side changes. I'm not sure, that this piece of code have been worked at all... But now need to modifiy it - without rebuilding of app)
